# Extension to keep annotations on arbitrary keywords

Tags: visual-studio-code

I’ve looked through the VSCode extension store and other random searches but have been unable to find what I’m looking for.  Before I dive into learning to write my own extension…

I am looking for a VSCode extension that will let me add keywords and custom annotations for those keywords in my code. In my head, specific words will be highlighted/underlined, and a small pop up will display notes that I have previously set for that keyword.

The primary use case is to remind me on specific use case or implications of particular keywords.  For instance, if I use the default HTTP client in Golang, I’d like to be reminded that there is no default timeout.

The definition would look something like:

```
“definitions”: [  
    {
      “text”: “http.Get”,
      “comment”: “the default go http client does not have a timeout.”
    }
]
```

Upon adding this line to my code

`*resp, err := http.Get("http://example.com/")`

would highlight/underline *http.Get* and when I mouseover, I will get a custom reminder that “the default http client does not have a timeout.”

Comment: what kind of quotes do you use in JSON files

Comment: use the extension **Highlight** to mark your texts, maybe add a feature request to add a HoverProvider for the given strings, or write a pull request for this, most of the work is already done